# Antd Pro EditableProTable inside ProForm is very slow

Tags: reactjs, performance, antd, ant-design-pro

The requirement is to have a form with an editable table inside as a field.
The following example achieves that but with only a few rows inside the table performance takes a hit (Editing and typing is laggy)

**CodeSandbox link:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/editableprotable-performance-issue-forked-y7qvf0?file=/App.tsx

**Minimal example to reproduce the issue:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ProForm, EditableProTable, ProColumns, ProCard } from '@ant-design/pro-components';

const defaultData = Array.from(Array(60), (_, index) => {
  return {
    id: index,
    product_name: `Product ${index}`,
    qty: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
    discount: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) / 100,
    type: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2).toString(),
  };
});

export default function Page() {
  const [editableKeys, setEditableRowKeys] = useState<React.Key[]>(() =>
    defaultData.map((item) => item.id),
  );

  const columns: ProColumns[] = [
    { dataIndex: 'id', title: 'ID', valueType: 'digit' },
    { dataIndex: 'product_name', title: 'Product', valueType: 'text' },
    { dataIndex: 'qty', title: 'Qty', valueType: 'digit' },
    { dataIndex: 'discount', title: 'Discount', valueType: 'digit' },
    {
      dataIndex: 'type',
      title: 'Type',
      valueType: 'select',
      valueEnum: {
        0: { text: 'Type A' },
        1: { text: 'Type B' },
        2: { text: 'Type C' },
      },
    },
    { dataIndex: 'comment', title: 'Comment', valueType: 'textarea' },
  ];

  return (
    <ProCard>
      <ProForm
        initialValues={{
          table: defaultData,
        }}
      >
        <EditableProTable
          formItemProps={{
            label: 'Product list',
          }}
          rowKey="id"
          name="table"
          scroll={{
            y: 540,
          }}
          columns={columns}
          recordCreatorProps={{
            record: (index) => {
              return { id: index };
            },
          }}
          editable={{
            type: 'multiple',
            editableKeys,
            onChange: setEditableRowKeys,
          }}
        />
      </ProForm>
    </ProCard>
  );
}
```

If we remove ProForm and leave EditableProTable only, and use defaultData as value={defaultData} there's no problem, everything is very fast.

Using another Component "ProFormList" for the same dataset does not seem to suffer from this issue. This means that the issue is not related to rendering around 300 to 500 text inputs.

Is there any solution or workaround for this ?